# How can I prevent WSL from freezing when running my model?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, wsl-2

I am trying to train a neural network on my computer using WSL. First I tried using a jupyter kernel to run the script line by line and it trained fro 10 epochs before WSL crashing inside VS Code and getting stuck in an endless reconnecting loop. Afterwards I tried running the script from the terminal and it has been stuck like in the pictures below (more than 1 hour since writing this).
Is there a way to prevent this?
Thank you!
[Performance View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDrCx.png)
[Process View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdukF.png)

EDIT FROM HERE: This is my code as I am trying to run it. my goal is to implement Wave U Net with the MSE between the target and the input as loss.

```
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.init as init
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader,random_split
import torchaudio
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


PARENT_FOLDER = "/mnt/c/Users/Tudor/Documents/yt-dlp"

SCALER = MinMaxScaler()

class DownSamplingLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channel_in, channel_out, dilation=1, kernel_size=9, stride=1, padding="same"):
        super(DownSamplingLayer, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(channel_in, channel_out, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                      stride=stride, padding=padding, dilation=dilation),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(channel_out),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1, inplace=True),
        )

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.main(x)
        return self.dropout(x)

class UpSamplingLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channel_in, channel_out, kernel_size=9, stride=1, padding="same"):
        super(UpSamplingLayer, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(channel_in, channel_out, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                      stride=stride, padding=padding),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(channel_out),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1, inplace=True),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.main(x)
    

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_layers=8, channels_interval=16):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.channels_interval = channels_interval

        encoder_in_channels_list = [1] + [i * self.channels_interval for i in range(1, self.n_layers)]
        encoder_out_channels_list = [i * self.channels_interval for i in range(1, self.n_layers + 1)]

        self.encoder = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            self.encoder.append(
                DownSamplingLayer(
                    channel_in=encoder_in_channels_list[i],
                    channel_out=encoder_out_channels_list[i]
                )
            )

        self.middle = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(self.n_layers * self.channels_interval, self.n_layers * self.channels_interval, kernel_size=3, stride=1,
                      padding="same"),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(self.n_layers * self.channels_interval),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1, inplace=True)
        )

        decoder_in_channels_list = [(2 * i + 1) * self.channels_interval for i in range(1, self.n_layers)] + [
            2 * self.n_layers * self.channels_interval]
        decoder_in_channels_list = decoder_in_channels_list[::-1]
        decoder_out_channels_list = encoder_out_channels_list[::-1]

        self.decoder = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            self.decoder.append(
                UpSamplingLayer(
                    channel_in=decoder_in_channels_list[i],
                    channel_out=decoder_out_channels_list[i]
                )
            )

        self.out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(1+self.channels_interval, 1, kernel_size=1, stride=1),
            nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1, inplace=True)
        )

        # Initialize the weights
        self.initialize_weights()

    def initialize_weights(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv1d) or isinstance(m, nn.ConvTranspose1d):
                init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight, gain=1.0)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm1d):
                init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
                init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

    def forward(self, x):
        tmp = []
        o = x
        # Up Sample
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            o = self.encoder[i](o)
            tmp.append(o)
            o = F.max_pool1d(o, kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        o = self.middle(o)

        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            o = F.interpolate(o, scale_factor=2, mode="linear", align_corners=True)
            o = torch.cat((o, tmp[self.n_layers - i - 1]), dim=1)
            o = self.decoder[i](o)
        o = torch.cat((o, x), dim=1)
        o = self.out(o)
        return o
    

input_samples, target_samples = np.load("input_samples.npy"), np.load("target_samples.npy")
input_samples =input_samples.tolist()
target_samples =target_samples.tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame({"input":input_samples,"target":target_samples})
class BassenhanceDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.input = df["input"]
        self.target = df["target"]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input = self.input[idx]
        target = self.target[idx]

        input = torch.tensor(input, dtype=torch.float32).T
        target = torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.float32).T

        return input, target
    
    
    def get_loader(self, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0):
        return DataLoader(self, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, num_workers=num_workers, collate_fn=self.collate_fn)
    
    def transpose(self, data):
        return data.transpose(1,2)
    
    def get_loader_transpose(self, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0):
        return DataLoader(self, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, num_workers=num_workers, collate_fn=self.collate_fn, drop_last=True)
    
    def split(self, train_size=0.8, shuffle=True):
        return torch.utils.data.random_split(self, [int(len(self) * train_size), len(self) - int(len(self) * train_size)], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))


def train_epoch(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion, device):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        input, target = input.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(input)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    return running_loss / len(train_loader)

def validate_epoch(model, val_loader, criterion, device):
    model.eval()
    running_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i, (input, target) in enumerate(val_loader):
            input, target = input.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(input)
            loss = criterion(output, target)
            running_loss += loss.item()
    return running_loss / len(val_loader)

def train(model, train_loader, val_loader, optimizer, criterion, device, epochs=10):
    train_losses = []
    val_losses = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        train_loss = train_epoch(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion, device)
        val_loss = validate_epoch(model, val_loader, criterion, device)
        train_losses.append(train_loss)
        val_losses.append(val_loss)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1} | Train Loss: {train_loss:.10f} | Val Loss: {val_loss:.10f}")
        save_state(model, epoch + 1)
        if early_stopping(val_losses, patience=50):
            print("Early Stopping")
            break
    return train_losses, val_losses

def plot_losses_real_time(train_losses, val_losses):
    plt.plot(train_losses, label="Train Loss")
    plt.plot(val_losses, label="Val Loss")
    plt.title("Losses")
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.ylabel("Loss")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def early_stopping(val_losses, patience=5):
    if len(val_losses) < patience:
        return False
    else:
        return val_losses[-1] > val_losses[-2] > val_losses[-3]
    


def save_state(model, epoch, path = "models"):
    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        state = { "epoch": epoch, "state_dict": model.state_dict(), "optimizer": optimizer.state_dict() }
        torch.save(state, os.path.join(path, f"model_{epoch}.pth"))
        print("Saved model")

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(f"Using {device} device")


model = Model(5,32).to(device)
# Mean Squared Error Loss
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00002)

dataset = BassenhanceDataset(df)
train_dataset, val_dataset = dataset.split()
print(f"Train dataset size: {len(train_dataset)}")
print(f"Val dataset size: {len(val_dataset)}")

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
valid_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
train_losses, val_losses = train(model, train_loader, valid_loader, optimizer, criterion, device, epochs=100)
plot_losses_real_time(train_losses, val_losses)
save_state(model, 100)
```

Comment: We cannot debug problems for you from just a vague screenshow, do not forget this is a coding site, and you should be aware of what your code does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Dr.Snoopy, I added my code in an edit.

Comment: the etiquette on this site is to checkmark your accepted answer to any question you post ... it tells us which answer is best and the system gives you some reputation points for that effort ... welcome to SO

Comment: It says I can accept my own answer in 2 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out what the problem was

The issue was with the DataLoader

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
valid_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

changing the num_workers to `num_workers=0` fixed the issue, [this webpage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeguru/detector-library/python/pytorch-data-loader-with-multiple-workers/) explains it why better than I could.